# Merge pull request automatically after success from travis

Tags: bash, git, github, travis-ci

I need to automate the process of merging the pull request to github master branch after Travis finishes the tests successfully, But I get this error `fatal: protocol '@github.com/https' is not supported`, the pull request is done on `For-testing` branch

I've followed the tutorial here [https://medium.com/@allanbrados/automerge-with-travis-ci-and-coveralls-to-elixir-248d1c6d2531] with some changes

I'm new to the CI process, also  didn't write bash before so I'm confused about many things

I tried the code below, but it errors, so anyone can help many. If there's another issue in the code tell me, please

```
#!/bin/bash -e



export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='shroukmansour99@gmail.com'
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='ShroukMansour'

printf '1>>>>>>>>>>>>>.\n'
git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* || exit
git fetch --all || exit

printf '\nb2>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'
git checkout master || exit
git merge --no-ff origin/For-testing || exit

printf '3>>>>>>>>>\n'
git push @github.com/"https://<GITHUB_TOKEN>@github.com/ShroukMansour/E-learning.git"

printf '4>>>>>>>>>>>>n'
```

I changed the GITHUB_token with my token generated from github

Answer (score 0):

> git push @github.com/"https://@github.com/ShroukMansour/E-learning.git"

This is wrong syntax. You need

```
git push https://<GITHUB_TOKEN>@github.com/ShroukMansour/E-learning.git
```

Comment: it gives remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed !!

Comment: Is your `GITHUB_TOKEN` correct? How do you pass it? Write directly in the bash script?

Comment: yes it's correct, I added it in the place of <GITHUB_TOKEN> like git push https://abcdefghjndfdnfonfornfd@github.com/ShroukMansour/E-learning.git